# AsyncTask java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой. При нажатии на кнопу должны отправляться данные на сервер.

```
buttonBy1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonBy1);
    buttonBy1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str;
            try {
                File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), MainActivity.FILENAME);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println( "Fail sozdan");
                }
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                str = br.readLine();
                if (str == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Telefon.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else  {
                    MyTask mt = new MyTask();
                    mt.execute(str);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("FAIL NE SOZDAN");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // указываем адрес вашего сервера и путь принимающего скрипта
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://aqualine09.ru/send.php");
        try {
            List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(2);
            for (String x : params) {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", x));
            }
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost); // отправка на сервер

            // отправляемое сообщение

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ...
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Вылетает ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        Process: com.ferisov.aqualive, PID: 9256
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
       at com.ferisov.aqualive.FirstFragment$MyTask.doInBackground(FirstFragment.java:170)
       at com.ferisov.aqualive.FirstFragment$MyTask.doInBackground(FirstFragment.java:152)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
```

Что ему не нравится?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в манифест:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Прописал это сразу, но сделал небольшую ошибку. Теперь все работает!